# MKMapView resets after changing the view

Tags: ios, xcode, mkmapview, mapkit, core-location

I have a problem with `MKMapView`which keeps resetting after I change the current view to an other one and I go back to the map again. In fact the first time everything goes well and the map is correctly centered on the user location but not the second time.

Here's my code:

**MapViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface MapViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;

@end
```

**MapViewController.m**

```
#import "MapViewController.h"

@interface MapViewController ()

@end

MKMapView *mapView;

@implementation MapViewController

@synthesize mapView;

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)aMapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)aUserLocation
{
    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.latitudeDelta = 0.009;
    span.longitudeDelta = 0.009;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
    location.latitude = aUserLocation.coordinate.latitude;
    location.longitude = aUserLocation.coordinate.longitude;
    region.span = span;
    region.center = location;

    [aMapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;

        if (result.height == 480)
        {
            mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 64, 320, 416)];
            mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
            mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeHybrid;
            mapView.delegate = self;
        }

        if (result.height == 568)
        {
            mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 64, 320, 504)];
            mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
            mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeHybrid;
            mapView.delegate = self;
        }
    }

    [self.view addSubview:mapView];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

@end
```

And here's some pictures

**First time:**
[image]

**Second time:**
[image]

Thanks to everyone will help me fixing this problem, have a good day!

Comment: I couldnt get the real issue, can you explain what you mean by "reset"?

Comment: OKay i got. are you talking about the zoom level?

Comment: @Deepukjayan Correct! But also the fact that the map is not centered on the user's position like the first time. Sorry for my english by the way.

Comment: when ever you move out of the view, store the zoomLevel and location cordinates using map.center. Then when you come back again set the map centre and zoom level to it.

Comment: Create a different method to update the region, and add this to it
MKCoordinateRegion region;
    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.latitudeDelta = 0.009;
    span.longitudeDelta = 0.009;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
    location.latitude = self.yourmapview.userlocation.coordinate.latitude;
    location.longitude = self.yourmapview.userlocation.coordinate.longitude;
    region.span = span;
    region.center = location;

    [self.yourMapView setRegion:region animated:YES];

Call that in viewdidload after doing what ever that you are already doing. call same in didUpdateUserLocation also

Comment: viewdidload or viewwillappear as per your need. Give it a try i am tying from memory so some typos might be there. I am sure you can solve it.

Comment: @santhu Thank you for your suggestion, can you show me how to do it in a separate answer? So if that will fix my problem I can select it as the best one for my question.

Comment: @Deepukjayan Wow that was fast! Thank you :-). Can you write it in an answer so I can select it as the one that fixed my problem?

Comment: did that work? Then i will post it

Comment: @Deepukjayan nope :-/ that didn't work, also what do you mean by:"Call that in viewdidload after doing what ever that you are already doing. call same in didUpdateUserLocation also"?. Can you post it in an answer so it will be more clear to me?. Thank you.

Comment: @Aluminum Okay. give it try and let me know. In case it doesnt work we can look for work around.

Comment: 1) Why do you have another global `mapView` declared in the .m file just above the @implementation?  You don't need it.  2) In the .h, you have a mapView that is marked as an IBOutlet so you have it connected to a map view in the xib, right?  So why are you creating and adding a new one in viewDidLoad?  3) Is this _all_ the code in the MapViewController.m?  Do you do _anything_ else with the mapView in the .m file?  4) How _exactly_ do you "change the current view to another one and go back"?  Can you show that code?

Comment: @Anna First, thank you for your comment!.
1) Ok, I will remove it :-)
2) Yes, it's connected to a map view in the .xib. Can you explain it better? What do you mean by "creating and adding a new one in viewDidLoad"?
3) Yes, that's all the code regarging "mapView", I have other code too off course but that's not for "mapView".
4) I switch views using a UIButton [the one at top, named "Fatto"] and then I go back using another UIButton in another view. I can't show you the code because I have used storyboard actions (segue) to do that.

Comment: 2) In viewDidLoad, you are doing alloc+initWithFrame of a MKMapView.  This _creates_ a new map view.  Then you do addSubview with that new map view.  This _adds_ the new map view on top of the one that you already added in the xib.  4) When you "go back", are you sure you are really going back to the original MapViewController and not creating a _new instance_ of another MapViewController and presenting that one (on top of the Fatto view)?

Comment: @Anna 2) Mhmm well you're right ^^" but how can I change my code to avoid creating a new map view every time I switch to the view containing the map view? In fact if I remove "[self.view addSubview:mapView];" the map will be like the "second time" [ http://bit.ly/1m4V0T4 ] :-/
4) Yes, I'm sure about it because storyboard always releases the current view as soon as you switch to new view [as far as I know].

Comment: It sounds like the delegate outlet of the map view in the xib is not connected to File Owner.  You have to connect two things: the mapView IBOutlet in File Owner to the map view control and the delegate outlet in the map view control to File Owner.  You definitely should not be creating and adding a new map view in viewDidLoad if you already have one in the xib.

Comment: @Anna I don't know if this can help you understanding the problem but here's a picture: http://bit.ly/1akJ9hz . Do I have to connect the Map View delegate outlet to the view?

Comment: The delegate outlet should be connected to the orange circle icon at the bottom (the icon to the left of the red cube).  Then comment out the whole viewDidLoad method.

Comment: @Anna Done, but the result it's still the same :-/, the first time it works but the second one don't :-(

Comment: You'll have to do some debugging with NSLogs, etc to find out why it doesn't zoom in the second time.  Put an NSLog in the didUpdateUserLocation delegate method to make sure it's getting called the second time.  If not, somehow the map's delegate is getting setting to nil.  Maybe you are calling setRegion somewhere else that's interfering.  Until you find out _why_ it's happening, I don't recommend implementing the answers below.

Comment: Also, when you "go back", if you are really coming back to the original MapViewController instance, then the view should be exactly as it was when you tapped Fatto _unless_ you have code in viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear, etc that changes something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a different method to update the region

```
-(void)yourMethod{

MKCoordinateRegion region; 
MKCoordinateSpan span; 
span.latitudeDelta = 0.009; 
span.longitudeDelta = 0.009; 
CLLocationCoordinate2D location; 
location.latitude = self.yourmapview.userlocation.coordinate.latitude; 
location.longitude = self.yourmapview.userlocation.coordinate.longitude; 
region.span = span; 
region.center = location; 
[self.yourMapView setRegion:region animated:YES]; 
}

-(void)viewWillAppear{
//After [self.view addSubview:mapView];
[self yourMethod];
}
```

Give it a try but dont update your "didUpdateUserLocation" now. Also let me know if you have a value in "yourMapView.location" inside "viewWillAppear" method.

Comment: Thank you for your kind help, but your code doesn't work, in fact the result is the same as before :-/. I have not set a value to "mapView.location". Also, following your code, do I have to replace "viewDidLoad" with "viewWillAppear"?

Comment: you can use mapview.userlocation . Also viewdidload and viewwillappear are two different methods. You cant simply replace one with other.

Comment: Thank you again, I have tried another time [with viewWillAppear, replacing it with viewDidLoad and viceversa] but it still doesn't work :-(. I don't know which is the problem :-/

Answer (score 1):

I went over the docs and found a mapView property **visibleMapRect**  
When you are pushing new view store this value as class property. 
ex:

```
@property MkMapRect currentRect;
```

initialise `currentRect = CGRectZero;`

Before pushing new view,

```
currentRect = mapView.visibleMapRect;
```

When you later come to this view, then mapView delegate will be called and in one of the delegate methods write below Code

```
if (currentRect.size.width!=0)
  [mapView setVisibleMapRect:currentRect animated:YES].
```

It will work.

Comment: Can you explain it better to me? For example using the code I have posted in my question? I don't know exactly where to put those lines you wrote :-/

Comment: visibleMapRect property holds the location and zoom level of mapView.SO you store this value when you are moving away from mapView to another View.When you comeback from otherView to mapView ,set the region of mapView using this method so your mapview will show last location.

Comment: Thank you again, but could you please write some code in to the one I have posted in my question to let me understand better where I have to put those lines of code? I'm an amateur programmer :-/. Thank you really much for your time @santhu :-)